# Remove GDM Completely

Tags: apt, gnome, lightdm, lxde, gdm

I recently tried installing Gnome Ubuntu Desktop from here https://popey.com/blog/posts/my-ubuntu-1604-gnome-setup.html

During the installation, I remember gdm3 asking me to set some kind of default file within a directory to make it default one. I accepted it and fast forward, I didn't really like Gnome and wanted to remove it.

I did all purge, and `sudo apt-get remove gnome-ubuntu-desktop` and all that. But still, the grey color screen comes when I start the system and the same screen comes when I shutdown the sytem albeit with a blue color loading icon in the center.

I want it to display "Ubuntu" as it was displaying. I don't know how to remove this gdm3 display manager completely.

I've reconfigured dpkg to use lightdm, but the gdm3 screen is somehow still preceding the lightdm's login screen AND, I've removed gdm3 in every which way I found on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Start in text-only mode

```
Switch on your computer. Wait until the BIOS has finished loading, and press and hold Shift, which will bring up the Grub menu.

Select the line which starts with Advanced options.

Select the line ending with (recovery mode)

Press Return and your machine will begin the boot process.

After a few moments, your PC should display a menu with a number of options, including Drop to root shell prompt. Press Return with this option highlighted.

The PC will start in a terminal.
```

Run these commands:

Mount partitions in read-write mode

```
mount -o remount,rw /
mount --all
```

Update repositories

```
apt-get update
```

Install aptitude and deborphan

```
apt-get install --reinstall aptitude deborphan
```

Eliminate the components of gnome that are not necessary in Ubuntu

```
aptitude remove '?and(?reverse-depends(gnome),?not(?reverse-depends(?exact-name(ubuntu-desktop))))'
```

Reinstall ubuntu-desktop

```
apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

Eliminate orphan packages

```
deborphan
apt-get --purge remove $(deborphan)
deborphan --libdevel
apt-get --purge remove $(deborphan --libdevel)
deborphan --find-config
dpkg --purge $(deborphan --find-config)
```

Remove unnecessary packages

```
apt-get autoremove
```

Remove downloaded packages

```
apt-get clean
```

Restart system

```
reboot
```

Comment: any idea how much data this will consume, because I don't want to end up not having enough data

Comment: I did all those commands and still the grey screen at the start and the end loading animation during switching off hasn't gone.

Comment: dont i need to start network services? selecting that option goes into normal resume & hangs.